# How to clear Cognito Id from cache in ios

Tags: amazon-cognito

After logging out of an iOS app when I login as a new user getIdentityId() returns the Cognito Id of the previous user.

Has anyone gotten multi-user accounts working with AWSCognito in iOS?

Answer (score 4):

The Cognito Id is stored in the keychain. You can clear the keychain using the AWS iOS SDK to completely get rid of the old Cognito Id. For example:

```
// check if a Cognito Id exists    
if identityProvider.identityId != nil {   // AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
    // delete the old Cognito Id
    identityProvider.clearKeychain()
    assert(identityProvider.identityId == nil)
}

// Get a new Cognito identity
let task: AWSTask = identityProvider.getIdentityId()
task.continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject? in
    if let error = task.error {
        completion(error: error)
    } else {
        // The new cognito identity token is now stored in the keychain.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. That is the code I'm calling. But if then log in as another user the app is given access to the previous user's cognito data. However, if I quit the app after calling identityProvider.clearKeychain() and then relaunch and login as that second user, all is fine and the second app instance isn't given access to the first user's cognito data.

Comment: Could it be the case that the cached AWS credentials are still being used? The AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider api http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.html#//api/name/credentials has functions clearCredentials and invalidateCachedTemporaryCredentials.

Comment: That was my thinking too so I called all 3. In this order: invalidateCachedTemporaryCredentials(), clearCredentials(), clearKeychain(). Are you using Cognito on iOS?

Comment: mmm, I'm out of suggestions... Yes I do, here's an example using Cognito http://peterfennema.nl/exploring-aws-as-a-backend-for-a-swift-app-3/  I'm developing an iOS app with AWS serverless backend.

Comment: Thanks anyway for pitching in. I'll check out your sample code. But out of interest I've you tried logging out of one user account and then logging in to another and seeing which Cognito database is changed?

Comment: You may find that this is an issue with AWS Cognito on iOS and so would affect your sample app should you add a Logout functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I did report a similar issue when using mobile hub helper here https://github.com/aws/aws-mobilehub-helper-ios/issues/14

But that was just data stored in NSUserDefaults by the AWSSignInProviders for Google and Facebook, I did not experience being able to sync data from a different identityId.  Are you sure that is what you are seeing?

One comment, if you use different authentication providers you may accidentally merge the two identities (login with google then with facebook).  So make sure that you are looking at different identityIds because if they are merged then they get their sync datasets merged.

Lastly... getIdentityId is not enough to switch identities.  You need to follow that with a call got get the credentials, if not the credentials never goes and calls "logins" with your identityProviderManager and gets the new authenticated state. - so login is get-id followed by get credentials for id.  Logout would be the same if you wanted to be an unauthenticated user (log out so your logins dictionary is empty, then getid, getcredentials... and you will be have unauthenticated credentials.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll only using one authentication provider (Auth0). Still have the same behaviour (aws sdk 2.5.1). But if I crash or close my app after logging out then the next user to log in, is cleanly logged in w/o access to the previous user's cognitosync data.